# Styling fusion table layers polygons

Tags: css, google-fusion-tables, layer

I have a fusion table with 5 populations (columns), for each these I want to display the polygons with the highest concentration of population in a different color.

In the example for styling fusion table layers, the "polygonOptions" was defined, but I don't want the polygons to have any styling unless there's a concentration of one of the populations, and also because that would take 1 style away from the limit of 5.

I'm not sure what to change or what I'm missing to have these styles display correctly.

My map: http://seflculturemap.com/miami-test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you have are the column-names, when they contain whitespaces, you must wrap them in single-quotes inside the query.

The other issue(that you need to apply 6 styles but there is a limit of 5). You also may create styles directly for a map, so you may create a dummy-style that sets the opacity of all polygons to 0.

To apply this style use the ID of the style and pass it with the options-parameter to the Layer. I've created such a dummy-style for your map, it does have the ID `4`

The layer-creation now should look like this:
var layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({

```
  query: {
    select: 'geometry',
    from:   '1PM3_L795Eus1HXCylF6UM0tLqXarnkNZeB_LmM8'

  },
  options: {
        styleId: 4
      },
  styles: [
     {
        where: "'Puerto Rican Population' > 500",
    polygonOptions: {
     fillColor: "#46A2D1", //blue
     fillOpacity: 0.7}  
     },
   {
        where: "'Cuban Population' > 500",
    polygonOptions: {
     fillColor: "#F29400", //orange
     fillOpacity: 0.7 }   
     }, 
     {
        where: "'Bahaman Population' > 100",
    polygonOptions: {
     fillColor: "#BAC200", //yellow
     fillOpacity: 0.7}  
     },  
     {
        where: "'Dominican Population' >200",
    polygonOptions: {
     fillColor: "#E068A0", //pink
     fillOpacity: 0.7 }   
     },
     {
        where: "'Haitian Population' > 500",
    polygonOptions: {
     fillColor: "#66A919", //green
     fillOpactity: 0.7}
   }
    ]
});
```

Test: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8mZuB/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8mZuB/)

---

**Related to the comments:**

you are using wrong column-names.

For http://www.seflculturemap.com/maps/central-american-populations.html:

```
'Nicaraguan' -> 'Nicaraguan Population'
```

For http://www.seflculturemap.com/maps/south-american-populations.html:

```
'Venezuelan Population'  ->'Venzuelan Population
'Peruvian'               ->'Peruvian Population'
'Argentinian Population' ->'Argentinean Population'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I can't believe I forgot about the quotations.
Where does the ID 4 come from? is it a default in fusion tables? 

I also added a legend using another tutorial in google developers, but unlike their example, the legend box gets pushed to the bottom of the map, once again I think this is a conflict in css styles (where I'm putting them or maybe they are overriding each other?)

This is where the map is now [link](http://seflculturemap.com/caribbean-populations.html)

Comment: I've created a new map-view(Map 2), and after applying the style for the polygons I went to **publish->get html and javascript** to see which ID the style does have.

Comment: I used this same html as a template to display 2 other maps, and even after double checking that the map id was correct, as well as the column names, I get the "data still loading" box for these two.

http://www.seflculturemap.com/maps/central-american-populations.html

http://www.seflculturemap.com/maps/south-american-populations.html

I don't know what could be amiss :( @dr.molle

Comment: you should have checked the column-names 3 times, see my edited answer.