# how to work around with fusion table styles limited to 5

Tags: javascript, maps, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table. I use the following javascript code to toggle 2 styles.

```
fusionTableLayer.setOptions({
            styles: styles1
        });

fusionTableLayer.setOptions({
            styles: styles2
        });
```

Problem is my style2 has more than 7 styles. But because of the limitation of fusiontable, the 6th and 7th styles doesn't work. How can work around this?

```
stylesIMD = [{        
        where: 'myVar <= 5',
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#27FF24',
        }
    }, {
        where: 'myVar > 5 AND myVar <= 10',
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#7BFB1E',
        }
    }, {
        where: 'myVar > 10 AND myVar <= 20',
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#D1F71A',
        }
    }, {
        where: 'myVar > 20 AND myVar <= 30',
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#F4C015',
        }
    }, {
        where: 'myVar > 30 AND myVar <= 40',
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#F06110',
        }
    }, {
        where: 'myVar > 40 AND myVar <= 50',
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#ED0B15',
        }        
    }, {
        where: 'myVar > 50',
        polygonOptions: {
            // fillColor: '#5C0517',
            strokeWeight: strokeWeight
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Can you style the map the way you want with the user interface?

Comment: Hi Geocodezip. thanks for your reply. Saw you did many replies on the mapping area. Anyway, the answer is I can't, at least i can't find a way to style it using fusiontable interface, because I need to toggle 2 styles.

Comment: Set up the more complicated mapping using the FusionTables interface, use the code generated by the UI to display that, then change to the less complicated style dynamically.

Comment: Geocodezip, I kinda understand what you mean. but don't know how to achieve it. Could you give me an example just using my code above? I need to toggle 2 styles dynamically. And one of the style has a list of 7 colors (fusiontable only allows 5 colors).

Comment: you mentioned using the code generated by the UI to display it? then change style dynamically? I do not understand how I can mix the 2 technique

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Related question: [Styling fusion table layers polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674143/styling-fusion-table-layers-polygons)

Comment: That topic only has 5 options in one style. But I have 7 options for one style.

Comment: Read the answer starting with: "The other issue(that you need to apply 6 styles but there is a limit of 5). You also may create styles directly for a map..."

Comment: Forgive my stupidness, I've read through the example a few times, but all I can tell is that the user only used 5 options in the style list. Maybe it is my English, but I can't see how he solved the limit of 5 styles? (or did he solve it?).

Comment: Second request: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue

Answer (score -1):

Answer is simple: you cannot.
Google basically caches all(!) tiles for your map as raster images on their servers. When you use styles, all tiles need to be cached again. They are limiting the number of styles to not to exhaust their caches. Consider using a locally/privately hosted gis solution to work around your issue. E.g: GeoServer+OpenLayers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really want to stay with Google map. That's why I want to find a work around.